# Select tab in Control Panel - Cytoscape

Tags: select, controls, panel, mean, cytoscape

I am unsure if Cytoscape has been updated since this was written in the protocol.. but the control panel looks significantly different than shown in the protocol and from there the "Mean log2FC". I can't find the "select" tab so I cannot move forward with the task.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLExF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's changed a bit, but the select tab looks the same once you get there.  Look to the left-hand-side of the control panel and you'll see "Network", "Style", "Filter", and "Annotation" (and perhaps others, depending on what apps you have loaded).  The select tab has been renamed "Filter", but it functions in exactly the same way.  Click on Filter, and you'll get the interface that used to be called "Select".